# I want to make event listner work only one time when i call the function eventGame()

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, event-handling

When i call the function eventGame() i want to make sure the event listners only work one time and after that they recall of function should be there for them to work them. For eg I want rock button to listen to event and after that scissors and papaer event listner should stop working until I call eventGame again.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><Rock-Paper-Scissors></Rock-Paper-Scissors></title>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Rock Paper Scissors</h3>
    <button id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button id="paper">Paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
    <script>
        function getComputerChoice() {

            let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            if (a == 1) {
                return "rock";
            }
            else if (a == 2) {
                return "paper";
            }
            else {
                return "scissors";
            }
        }
        function playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection) {
            if (computerSelection == playerSelection) { return ("Draw"); }
            else if (computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "paper") { return "Win"; }
            else if (computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "rock") { return "Loose"; }
            else if (computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "rock") { return "Win"; }
            else if (computerSelection == "rock" && playerSelection == "scissors") { return "Loose"; }
            else if (computerSelection == "paper" && playerSelection == "scissors") { return "Win"; }
            else if (computerSelection == "scissors" && playerSelection == "paper") { return "Loose"; }
            else { return "Draw"; }

        }
        function fetchToPlayRound(choice) {
            let playerSelection = choice;
            const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
            check=playRound(computerSelection, playerSelection);
            console.log(check);
            console.log("computer choice is")
            console.log(computerSelection);
            console.log("player choice is")
            console.log(playerSelection);



        }
        function eventGame() {

            const rockBtn = document.querySelector('#rock');
            const paperBtn = document.querySelector('#paper');
            const scissorsBtn = document.querySelector('#scissors');
            rockBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>fetchToPlayRound('rock'),{once:true});
            paperBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>fetchToPlayRound('paper'),{once:true});
            scissorsBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>fetchToPlayRound('scissors'),{once:true});

        }
        eventGame();




    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I expect the eveng listner to work only once